Backtesting.py not 100% win rate when using data for AI model
I have been working on a data model to train an AI, in order to ensure that the model is correct before training, etc, I run a backtest.py to make sure it will win all trades, as the data is already there to make it 100% win rate.
So this is basically just a way to validate the data model before training. Strangely with Buys after some issues. it finally worked, with Sells I can't really find the issue.
I have created a minimum example to see, if it could be a pandas issue or backtest.py or myself.
# requirements.txt maybe not all of them are needed to run this minimum code but just in case

pandas
numpy
ta
pandas_ta
plotly
kaleido
backtesting
tqdm
bokeh==2.4.3

# demo1.csv with only 10 rows

Date,Time,Open,High,Low,Close,Volume
20240819,18:00:00,2502.98,2504.34,2502.32,2503.05,613950
20240819,18:30:00,2503.01,2504.72,2502.97,2504.18,575800
20240819,19:00:00,2504.16,2505.14,2502.95,2504.61,798150
20240819,19:30:00,2504.59,2505.75,2503.61,2505.34,823930
20240819,20:00:00,2505.51,2505.54,2503.45,2504.16,419860
20240819,20:30:00,2504.09,2504.46,2503.28,2503.89,294830
20240819,22:00:00,2503.28,2504.14,2501.93,2502.11,234130
20240819,22:30:00,2502.11,2504.47,2502.11,2504.14,186780
20240819,23:00:00,2504.14,2504.16,2502.41,2503.09,209580
20240819,23:30:00,2503.09,2503.68,2502.39,2503.51,184700

# dev.py python code
import pandas as pd

# import the data and minor modification to index by datetime
def get_data():
    df = pd.read_csv('demo1.csv')
    df['adj_close'] = df['Close']
    df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%Y%m%d')
    df['Time'] = pd.to_timedelta(df['Time'])
    df['datetime'] = df['Date'] + df['Time']
    df.index = df['datetime']
    df = df.drop(columns=['Date', 'Time', 'datetime'])
    return df

def prepare_data(df):
    # here I get the next row Low and High
    df["L1"] = df["Low"].shift(-1)
    df["H1"] = df["High"].shift(-1)

    df.dropna(inplace=True)

    # For simplicity I just add 2$ to the Close for the Stop loss and substract 2$ for the Take Profit.
    df['SellSL'] = df['Close'] + 2
    df['SellTP'] = df['Close'] - 2
    # This is where if the SL is higher than next bar High
    # and TP is smaller than next bar Low
    # it saves as 1, so a possible signal to sell
    df["SellPossibleFound"] = ( (df['SellSL'] > df["H1"]) & ( df['SellTP'] < df["L1"] ) ).astype(int)

    return df


from backtesting import Backtest, Strategy

class CheckData(Strategy):
    def init(self):
        pass
    def next(self):
        # if the flag is 1, then it will sell, using the SellSL and SellTP
        if self.data.SellPossibleFound > 0:
            self.sell(size=1, sl=self.data.SellSL, tp=self.data.SellTP)

df = get_data()
df = prepare_data(df)
bt = Backtest(df, CheckData)
stats = bt.run()
bt.plot()
print(stats)


At this point I start to think that it maybe a bug with the library, because I can't find the issue.

Your question is unclear to me. What do you mean by "to ensure that the model is correct before training, etc, I run a backtest.py to make sure it will win all trades"? Do you create a dummy model that knows the answers and always return the correct ones?

Basically the model, will predict if the next bar will go down 2$ without going up 2$, so I create a CSV from Stock data, that will have this populated, when this condition happens. Then just as an extra check I will run backtest.py to back test that all positions are winner, prior to creating the model. I could do it with if statements, but I may miss if there is a really mistake in the data.
